# Change bundle install location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I've somehow changed the configuration of bundle install, so it now creates a `/vendor/bundle` folder in my rails project, and puts all the gems there.

How can I reset my bundle config, so it installs the gems globally instead?

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `.bundle` directory from your project root and then do a `bundle install` instead of the `bundle install --path vendor` like previously.

The `.bundle/config` file stores the local path for installing gem location, if gems are installed within the app, and `bundler` picks up those settings next time onwards by default.